# Python tkinter : loop in Label

Tags: python, user-interface, loops, tkinter, label

Hello I just wanted that the Label change/refresh during the loop, but it doesn't work

This my code

```
fen1 = Tk()

v = StringVar()
Label(fen1,textvariable=v).pack()

i=0

while(1):
    i=i+1
    v.set(i)
fen1.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here, try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
root=Tk()

variable=StringVar()

def update_label():
    i=0
    while 1:
        i=i+1
        variable.set(str(i))
        root.update()

your_label=Label(root,textvariable=variable)
your_label.pack()
start_button=Button(root,text="start",command=update_label)
start_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

That should give you a good example. However, it is important to note that during the while loop, you MUST call `root.update()` otherwise your GUI will freeze until the loop completes (in this case it *never* does) and never show your numbers.

Also note that you *can* call `update_label()` from anywhere in your program. I just added it to the start button for example purposes.

What was wrong with your code was that you had set the while loop free-floating and most importantly *before* your GUI's mainloop. When you do this, since this loop is infinate, it never allows `Tkinter` to start its `mainloop()`. However, if you were to put the while loop *after* the mainloop, then that would never be executed until *after* you exit the GUI, this is because the mainloop is infinate until it is stopped (closing the GUI).

So to fix this you simply put it in a function and call it later on during `Tkinter`'s mainloop. You can do this various ways as well, for example, you can use `.after()` to perform a specific task after a certain amount of time, or make it the command of a button to be run when pressed, ect., ect. .

However, The *proper* code you should use is the following, as you do not really want infinate loops in your code (other then you mainloop).:

```
class App (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.variable=StringVar()
        self.i=0
        self.your_label=Label(self.root,textvariable=self.variable)
    def grid(self):
        self.your_label.pack()
    def update_label(self):
        self.i=self.i+1
        self.variable.set(str(self.i))
        self.root.after(20,self.update_label)
    def run(self):
        self.grid()
        self.root.after(20,self.update_label)
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().run()
```

Comment: -1: you should never call sleep in the main thread of a GUI. Doing so in an answer sets a bad example. You are wrong when you say that by calling `update` this never freezes. While the sleep is active, the UI _will_ be frozen, even if only for half a second.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok i changed that.

Comment: It's still not the right solution. In addition to not calling `sleep`, as a rule of thumb you shouldn't have infinite loops either. To update a label every half second you should take advantage of the event loop and use `after`

Comment: I was answering as close as the OP's code as i could. i can add that to my answer aswell though :)

Comment: @BryanOakley There, i added it.

Comment: root.update() is a line I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your code never gets to the `mainloop`.  In order to see something like this, you need to bind the update in a callback which gets called in the mainloop (indirectly, through events).